# Component dynamic progress bar function does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

so basically I made a separate progress bar component, it's a dynamic circular bar.
And I placed 2 of them in a dashboard component, the first one works very fine, but the second remains static at 0% and did not call the progress function.
ps: I use Tailwindcss Can you please help me fix that?

**Here is the Dashboard component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUserInfo } from '../actions/userActions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProgressBar from './progressBar';

class Dashboard extends Component {

    state = {
        user: {

        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getUserInfo();
        this.setState({
          user : this.props.currentUser
        })
    }

  render() {

    const { user } = this.state;


    return (
      <div className='w-full h-auto bg-slate-100 p-4'>

        { (user?.isLoggedIn == true) ? <div className='dashboard'>
          <div className='w-full flex h-auto mt-14'>

            <div className='border-2 border-slate-500 relative block text-center w-9/2 md:w-1/5 md:min-w-72 h-56 md:h-72 mr-2 mx-auto rounded-md'>
              <h1 className='balance text-2xl font-medium w-auto mx-auto mt-9 md:mt-20 md:font-semibold'>Personal balance</h1>
              <h1 className="balance text-3xl mt-6">0 $</h1>
            </div>
            <div className='border-2 border-slate-500 relative flex w-9/2 md:w-4/5 h-56 md:h-72 mx-auto rounded-md'>

            </div>

          </div>
          <div className='mt-2 p-2 border-2 border-slate-500 relative flex justify-between w-full h-56 md:h-64 mx-auto rounded-md'>
            <div className='w-28 h-28 md:w-36 md:h-36'>
              <ProgressBar percentage={99} />
            </div>
            <div className='w-28 h-28 md:w-36 md:h-36'>
              <ProgressBar percentage={99} />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div> : 

        // NOT LOGGED PAGE

        <div className='w-full h-screen block mt-24'>
          <h1 className="text-xl text-red-500">You are not logged yet</h1>
          <Link to="log-in"> Login here </Link>
        </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapUserStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        currentUser : state.user.user
    }
}

export default connect(mapUserStateToProps, { getUserInfo })(Dashboard);
```

**And here is the ProgressBar component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ProgressBar extends Component {


  render() { 

      let progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
      let valueContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-value');
      const speed = 20;
      let progressValue = 0;
      //let progressEndValue = 70;


      function updateElements() {
        valueContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-value');
        progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
      }

      const createProgress = setInterval(() => {
        updateElements();
        valueContainer.innerText = `${progressValue} %`
        progressContainer.style.background = `conic-gradient(
          rgb(239 68 68) ${progressValue*3.6}deg,
          black 1deg,
          rgb(251, 202, 202)  1deg
          )`
          
          if (progressValue == this.props.percentage) {
            clearInterval(createProgress);
          }
          progressValue++;
        }, speed) 

    return (
      <div className='progress-container w-full h-full rounded-full flex justify-center items-center'>
        <div className="w-3/4 h-3/4 rounded-full bg-slate-100 flex justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className='progress-value' >0 %</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}


export default ProgressBar;
```

Comment: can you provide a sandbox ?

Comment: Of course, here is the entire app repository in my GitHub account : https://github.com/TinySmash/banking-app.git

Comment: If you wanted to run the app you should sign-in (Not a real one, just enter random info respecting the regex), the go-to dashboard

Comment: By sandbox, I mean a reproducible code for just the case that create this issue